# A very strict inequality for $\ln n$ and $H_{n-1}$, with $n>2$, searching for proof

Tags: inequality, logarithms, harmonic-numbers

I have been fooling around with logarithms and experimentally found a very strict inequality from above (which I haven't been able to improve further):

> $$\ln n < H_{n-1}+\frac{1}{8(n-1)}+\frac{3}{8n}-\gamma \tag{1}$$

Here's the numerical check in Mathematica for $n=2 .. 2000$:

[image]

This is different from the usual asymptotic expansion of [Harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), and I'm not sure how to prove it. Any thoughts?

Maybe it's not true for larger $n$, so disproving it is also acceptable.

I would also like any sources for it, if it is already known (which I'm sure it is).

---

The usual asymptotics $$H_{n}\sim \ln {n}+\gamma +{\frac {1}{2n}}-\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac {B_{2k}}{2kn^{2k}}}=\ln {n}+\gamma +{\frac {1}{2n}}-{\frac {1}{12n^{2}}}+{\frac {1}{120n^{4}}}-\cdots$$

is of course better than (1), if we include the quadratic term, but worse if we only leave the linear term.

---

Mixing up those asymptotics up to the linear terms, I have found another inequality:

> $$H_{n-1} < \frac{1}{2} ( \ln (n-1) + \ln n) +\frac{3}{16} \left( \frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n} \right) - \gamma \tag{2}$$

or:

$$H_{n-1} <  \frac{1}{2} \ln n (n-1) +\frac{3}{16} \frac{1}{n(n-1)}  - \gamma$$

Which is even more strict, and I bet difficult to prove.

Comment: You can expand $1/(n-1)=n^{-1}(1+n^{-1}+n^{-2})+O(n^{-4})$. Comparing your estimate with the usual asymptotic up to $O(n^{-4})$ proves your inequality. The error you get for large $n$ grows like $1/(24n^2)$ if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Hamed, I didn't think of it, thanks. What about the second inequality? I suppose, I can use the series too, for both the logarithmic term and the fraction

Comment: I haven't thought about the second one but as a half physicist, my first instinct is to Taylor expand everything :)

Comment: Expanding gives us $$\ln (n+1)=\ln n+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2} -\dots\\ \frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}+\dots$$ which in the second expression gives us $$H_n \asymp \ln n+\frac{1}{2n}-\gamma-\frac{1}{16n^2}$$ if I'm not mistaken, which is close to the classical result, but not yet proof

Comment: I believe you need to also keep the $n^{-3}$ factors and calculate the difference of the two up to $O(n^{-4})$. Then the classical result should end up being less than your estimate.